# Remove Controller & function name from url using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I want to remove controller and function name from my url. my url looks like

example.com/config/addRoom.aspx

where "config" controller name & "addRoom" function/method name. I am using htaccess for remove index.php. and I configure my routes.php file like this

```
    $route['room'] = "config/addRoom";
```

but it's not working. pages are not found plz help

Comment: try url http://example.com/room

Comment: @RakeshSharma it redirect me the same page like this link example.com/config/addRoom.aspx when i write this url manually but i want when i visit 
example.com/config/addRoom.aspx this link by clicking menu that is
<?php echo anchor('config/addRoom', 'Room Config');?> my url will be look like example.com/room. haow can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Write "room" at the place from where you want the redirection .. 
like now you are writing

in Controller :-
redirect("config/addRoom") ;

Make It 
Redirect("room");

Or In View :-
now you are write like 
href="config/addRoom"

Please Make it

href="room"